# Numerous blocks with MySQL query writing NULL in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, block

I am working on a piece of code that writes data from 4 different `.each` blocks into 4 different MySQL rows in a table.

**Edit**: I should note that these four blocks are nested in one loop. I've figured out that it is stacking each db.query on top of the one before because it is generating a new ID for each of them. So, the code IS working...just not as intended. Basically, one row in the table should contain a column and corresponding data for a, b, c, and d. How can I use multiple blocks like this and make sure they're all writing to the same row?

The code looks a bit like this...

```
1.upto(5) do |num|
    a.each do |a|
      puts a
      db.query("INSERT INTO Table(Column1) VALUES('#{a}')")
    end

    b.each do |b|
      puts b
     db.query("INSERT INTO Table(Column2) VALUES('#{b}')")
    end

    c.each do |c|
      puts c
      db.query("INSERT INTO Table(Column3) VALUES('#{c}')")
    end

    d.each do |d|
      puts d
      db.query("INSERT INTO Table(Column4) VALUES('#{d}')")
    end
end
```

Obviously this is just an example but the blocks don't really differ much from this.

A few things.

First, yes, I need to have these four blocks with the `.each` because I am doing different things with them that I can't just do all in one block.

Second, I know that each of these blocks is "right" because if I comment out all of them but one, **it will write perform that one block correctly** - writing to the database, etc. With *all* of the blocks ***uncommented*** like they should be, it only writes block **'a'** to the database and the rest of the blocks don't write anything, leaving the rows NULL.

The 'puts' commands are outputting perfectly fine as expected - each block executing after the one before, there is just an issue when it is trying to do the query() method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Ruby before but perhaps you have an issue with disposing of the query object or properly initialising it again before using it for subsequent blocks?

Try re-initialising the query object.

Comment: I edited my original post. Turns out, each block will do it's thing and write to the database, but since I am doing a query numerous times in each block, it generates a unique ID each time, so instead of writing 4 different types of data to a row like I want it to, it is stacking them on top of each other in the table.

Comment: If you insist on doing it this way instead of building the query using an array and doing one insert per record, you can do `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the first block and make subsequent blocks do an UPDATE for their respective columns for the record with that ID.

What you should be doing is as I say building an array of data to insert and committing it all at once. Post your actual code here and let us help you properly.

Comment: I went with just storing them in an array and it works well. Thank you!